# Removing a row from tableview causing crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that loading data from array called `self.data` .
Then i am trying to remove a row, so first i remove it from the data array, then i am trying to remove it from the table view with :

```
 Data *d=[[Data alloc] init];
    [d removeObject:ID];

    NSLog(@"%ld",editingRow); //the right row to remove

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:editingRow inSection:0];


     //update table
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

the crash is this :

```
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code in `TableViewDelegate`

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    [d removeObject:ID];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ID inSection:0]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the same as what i do. I dont see how this answer brings something new.

Comment: you remove the object with ID, but have to remove according to indexPath.row.

Comment: Wrong. I am removing an object with ID because the data base order is different from the tableview order. Moreover it doesn't matter what row you remove but the number of rows in the db to be -1 .

Comment: Ok, its fine, I understand, You remove object from ID

Comment: You have to passing indexPath.row of ID.